# choosing between three boxes game

Tags: probability

you are a player in a game where each contestant has to choose between three boxes to win a prize. The prize is distributed uniformly between the three boxes. Each player makes a choice independent of one another. many or none of the players could choose the right box which is revealed at the end of each round. However, you have info that the other players don't- you know that the prize will be behind a different box from the previous round. Find the probability that you will have chosen the right box more than the other players by the end of the game.

The problem doesn't give me how many rounds per game or how many players there are which made me first think that there was an issue with the problem, but i'm not sure. Would appreciate if someone could please confirm or help me out if its possible. Thanks

Comment: Is there only one prize, it talks of **the** prize.  Do only **you** (as writtwn) have the extra information ?

Comment: only one prize, and only i have the extra info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a variation of the Monty Hall problem, also known as the three doors problem. In the original version of the problem, you make an initial choice. There is a car behind one door, which you are trying to win, and goats behind the other two doors, which you are trying to avoid winning. The twist is that the host of the game will reveal a door that has a goat behind it, then ask you if you wish to change your initial choice. You should always do so, because then your odds of winning the car increase to 2/3 from 1/3, because he has revealed extra information to you that you didn't have initially. Because he doesn't pick the doors randomly, i.e. he always reveals a door with a goat behind it, then asks you if you want to swap your original choice.

As I see it, here are the permutations for your variation of the game:

Round 1: You have no advantage, because it is the first round, your probability of guessing the correct box is 1/3.

Round 2 and subsequent rounds: There is a 1/3 possibility you guessed correctly in round 1.

Your probability of guessing correctly now increases to 1/2, because you now know that the prize is in one of two boxes. As long as you keep track of the revealed box, your probability will always be 1/2 for subsequent rounds after the first one.

To answer the question, their overall probability of guessing correctly remains constant at 1/3.  After the first round, your probability of guessing correctly is 1/2, so the probability you will have chosen the right box more than the other players is a smidgen less than 1/6, taking into account the fact that your probability is the same as theirs in the first round only, but greater than theirs by 1/6 for each subsequent round played.